# jQuery INVIEW is not working with a class added by another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, inview

In this first code, if you click `LIKE` it will add a class `.loved` to the active section: `.section .active`. (The `.active` class is added automatically by the fullpage plugin to the visible section).

And here you can see that the INVIEW plugin does not work.

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({});

$(document).on("click", ".like", function() {
  $('.section.active').addClass("loved")
})

$('.loved').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    console.log("IN VIEW")
  } else {
    console.log("GONE")
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10vw;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.section {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: grey;
  color: #141414;
}

.like {
  color: red;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: .3em;
  right: .3em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/protonet/jquery.inview/master/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">One</div>
  <div class="section">Two</div>
  <div class="section">Three</div>
  <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
<div class=like>LIKE</div>
```

In this second function, if I add the class `.loved` to the section, then the INVIEW works smoothly.
Any ideas?

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({});

$('.loved').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    console.log("IN VIEW")
  } else {
    console.log("GONE")
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10vw;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.section {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: grey;
  color: #141414;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/protonet/jquery.inview/master/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section loved">One</div>
  <div class="section">Two</div>
  <div class="section">Three</div>
  <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is in this line:

```
$('.loved').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
```

Because in the first snippet you add the class "in future" you need to delegate the event to the document:

```
$(document).on('inview', '.loved', function(event, isInView) {
```

Moreover, when creating a snippet, if you need to use a github lib you need to convert from:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/....
```

to:

```
https://rawgit.com/....
```

The snippet:

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({});

$(document).on("click", ".like", function() {
    $('.section.active').addClass("loved")
})

$(document).on('inview', '.loved', function(event, isInView) {
    if (isInView) {
        console.log("IN VIEW")
    } else {
        console.log("GONE")
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10vw;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.section {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: grey;
  color: #141414;
}

.like {
  color: red;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: .3em;
  right: .3em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/protonet/jquery.inview/master/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>


<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">Two</div>
    <div class="section">Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
<div class=like>LIKE</div>
```